# Visual studio community 2013 Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, outlook

I've just downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Community edition and trying to find why I can't find a Template for Outlook under Visual C#.

I find in other articles that you can find Templates > Visual C# > Office Add-ins -> Outlook 2013 Add-in

But I don't even have this option.

Do I need to download some other extension to enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to install http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2013 to get the templates visible.